# Extract double quoted string content with Parboiled

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-generator, parser-combinators, parboiled

I'm writing a parser, one of it's parts should match and retrieve double-quoted string content
It yields only quotation mark, but not whole string. For unquoted ones everything works well

Here is the corresponding rule:

```
def doubleQuoted: Rule1[StringWrapper] = rule { //same for singlequoted
  "\"" ~ zeroOrMore( noneOf("\"\\") | ("\\" ~ "\"") ) ~ "\"" ~> StringWrapper
}
```

The problem is:

- input ->  "directive"
- expected output -> StringWrapper("\"directive\"")
- real output -> StringWrapper("\"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found out the solution!

This code works well. Actually, my IDE highlited me that this part of code from my previous example

```
zeroOrMore( noneOf("\"\\") | ("\\" ~ "\"") )
```

has type Rule0. I forced it to Rule1
And, now it works.

```
def doubleQouteBody: Rule1[StringWrapper] = rule {
  zeroOrMore( noneOf("\"\\") | ("\\" ~ "\"") ) ~> StringWrapper
}

def doubleQuoted: Rule1[StringWrapper] = rule { //same for singlequoted
  "\"" ~ doubleQouteBody ~ "\""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you could use the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern for faster parsing. In Java:

```
Rule Normal()
{
    return NoneOf("\\\"");
}

Rule Special()
{
    return String("\\\"");
}

Rule NSN()
{
    return Sequence(
        ZeroOrMore(Normal()),
        ZeroOrMore(Special(), ZeroOrMore(Normal()))
    );
}

Rule DoubleQuotedString()
{
    return Sequence('"', NSN(), '"');
}
```